# Simultaneous triggers makes inserts and updates difficult

Tags: oracle, triggers, simultaneous, mutating-table

I have 4 tables in Oracle: `hotel`, `tourist`, `stay`, `leave`. The `stay` table relates a tourist staying in a hotel, and the `leave` table stores the information of the date when a tourist leaves a hotel.

```
CREATE TABLE hotel (
    id NUMBER(5),
    name VARCHAR2(50),
    tenants_amount NUMBER(3)
);

ALTER TABLE hotel ADD CONSTRAINT hotel_c1
CHECK(tenants_amount>=0 AND tenants_amount<=100);

CREATE TABLE tourist (
    id NUMBER(5),
    name VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE stay (
    tourist_id NUMBER(5),
    hotel_id NUMBER(5)
);

CREATE TABLE leave (
    departure_date DATE,
    hotel_id NUMBER(5),
    tourist_id NUMBER(5)
);
```

I'm interested in check if `tenants_amount` of an insert or update on `hotel` is consistent with the contents of the table `stay`, so I wrote this trigger for `hotel`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER hotel_trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON hotel
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    amount NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(tourist_id) INTO amount FROM stay WHERE hotel_id=:NEW.id GROUP BY hotel_id;
    IF :NEW.tenants_amount!=amount THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Specified tenants amount differs from the system records');
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        IF :NEW.tenants_amount!=0 THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Specified tenants amount differs from the system records');
        END IF;
END;
/
```

I also wrote a second trigger for storing the information of `leave` and the management of the `tenants_amount` attribute of `hotel`. This trigger fires when DML operations are made on `stay` because it's the table that represents this relation

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER stay_trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON stay
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    amount NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
        SELECT tenants_amount INTO amount FROM hotel WHERE id=:NEW.hotel_id;
        UPDATE hotel SET tenants_amount=amount+1 WHERE id=:NEW.hotel_id;
    END IF;
    IF UPDATING AND :NEW.hotel_id!=:OLD.hotel_id THEN
        SELECT tenants_amount INTO amount FROM hotel WHERE id=:OLD.hotel_id;
        UPDATE hotel SET tenants_amount=amount-1 WHERE id=:OLD.hotel_id;
        INSERT INTO leave VALUES (SYSDATE, :OLD.hotel_id, :OLD.tourist_id);
        SELECT tenants_amount INTO amount FROM hotel WHERE id=:NEW.hotel_id;
        UPDATE hotel SET tenants_amount=amount+1 WHERE id=:NEW.hotel_id;
    END IF;
    IF DELETING THEN
        SELECT tenants_amount INTO amount FROM hotel WHERE id=:OLD.hotel_id;
        UPDATE hotel SET tenants_amount=amount-1 WHERE id=:OLD.hotel_id;
        INSERT INTO leave VALUES (SYSDATE, :OLD.hotel_id, :OLD.tourist_id);
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Finally, I try to insert some rows:

```
INSERT INTO hotel VALUES (1,'Hotel 1',0);
INSERT INTO tourist VALUES (1, 'Tourist 1');
INSERT INTO stay VALUES (1, 1);
```

And I get the error from the hotel trigger:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: Specified tenants amount differs from the system records
ORA-06512: at "HOTEL_TRG", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HOTEL_TRG'
ORA-06512: at "STAY_TRG", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'STAY_TRG'
```

This is what happens: when the trigger of `stay` is fired it attempts to increase the `tenants_amount` of the hotel with `id=1`, this is an update that fires the trigger of `hotel`. The trigger of `hotel` checks if the `tenants_amount` is consistent with the contents of `stay` but the changes are still not visible and it doesn't find any row. It means that the `tenants_amount` should be 0 but the update on `hotel` setted it to 1.

I want to know how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Style note: you should write three distinct trigger,  on `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, instead of an single one with an `IF INSERTING` - al. inside.

Comment: It's usually best *not* to store data that can be *calculated*, unless or until it is demonstrated that computing the value during retrieval has a performance issue. In that way, you ensure the data is *always* accurate without having to create any triggers. (Or to put it another way, it's the *storing* of computable data that *introduces* the opportunity for inconsistency to appear)

Answer (score 0):

Make the trigger `stay_trg` `AFTER INSERT` instead of `BEFORE INSERT`